# php-After installing ffmpeg-php extension,i am not able to see the ffmpeg in phpinfo?

Tags: ffmpeg-php

I had Windows 7 Ultimate(64 bit) OS with wamp v2.2 (php 5.2.2 & php 5.3.13,apache v2.2.22, Mysql v5.5.24).
I tried to install 32-bit ffmpeg -php from  [this link.](http://sergey89.ru/files/ffmpeg-php/)on php v5.3.13 and i have followed the whole process of:unzipping,placing files as mentioned in right folders(system32 and ../bin/ext/) and also editing the php.ini(adding extension=php_ffmpeg.dll) but still i am not able to view this extension in phpinfo page even though when i go to wamp icon>PHP>Php Extensions, i can see the php_ffmpeg in the extension list but when i check phpinfo, nothing is seen. i can't post pics.but does there anything i can do???
or some settings which must be changed??anything will be quite helpful.thnxx....

Comment: when you try to use the ffmpeg functions, you get an error?

Comment: i get this error in apache_error_log file :PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_ffmpeg.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Comment: When you open the folder, does it really contain php_ffmpeg.dll ?